Commercial redistribution of Ubuntu
The company I work for is in the process of porting their software to run on Linux. I am one of the software developers working on this and a big part of my job is building the Linux image that the software runs on. We have been building custom Ubuntu OS images to run on our hardware, but we haven't modified any of the software that runs on Ubuntu itself.
In a nutshell, I use VMDB2 to create the base Ubuntu image from Ubuntu's official repositories. I do it this way to create a stripped-down OS image that has a bare-bones desktop environment and not much else. This is to reduce the size of the OS image. I also run a script that creates the user account, modifies some config files (to auto-login on boot, for example), and installs a few hardware drivers.
Now, the last few days there has been talk that we may switch our OS image to use Debian instead because of potential licensing issues. It seems that Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu, wants people to pay for a license to redistribute "modified" versions of Ubuntu.
Per their website:


You can redistribute Ubuntu, but only where there has been no modification to it.

You can redistribute Ubuntu in its unmodified form, complete with the installer images and packages provided by Canonical (this includes
the publication or launch of virtual machine images).

Any redistribution of modified versions of Ubuntu must be approved, certified or provided by Canonical if you are going to associate it
with the Trademarks. Otherwise you must remove and replace the
Trademarks and will need to recompile the source code to create your
own binaries. This does not affect your rights under any open source
licence applicable to any of the components of Ubuntu. If you need us
to approve, certify or provide modified versions for redistribution
you will require a licence agreement from Canonical, for which you may
be required to pay.



Ubuntu is essentially a collection of software, most of which are under open-source licenses. As far as I know, Canonical has not written any of the software running on Ubuntu, and therefore they do not own that software. To me, this seems like they're trying to side-step the open-source licenses and overlay their own license on top.
Also, the term "modify" seems ambiguous here. What exactly constitutes modifying Ubuntu? Again, it's a collection of software that Canonical does not own. It stands to reason that if Canonical does not own the individual elements, then they do not own the collection of those elements either. How can they claim intellectual property rights on something they don't own? How can they demand you pay a license fee to distribute a "modified" version of Ubuntu as part of a commercial product?
Note: I am not asking for hard legal advice here. My employer is speaking to a lawyer and contacting Canonical directly to determine how they want to move forward. This question is strictly for my own curiosity.

Linux is GPLed, which means that anyone can modify and redistribute it. What Canonical is claiming ownership of is their trademark on the distro, their original code that they include alongside the base Linux, and their organization of the distro. So if you make any changes that are within the GPL permissions, you can't call it Ubuntu any more.

And if you don't use their trademarks, you don't need to pay a license fee.

@Barmar Yeah, it does say you can remove all trademarks and recompile everything from source to avoid needing a license. That removes a big advantage though, which is the ability to get software updates via the package manager. Especially security updates.

Which is what you're paying them for. That doesn't come for free.

@Barmar I'd argue that it generally does. After all, private users of Ubuntu don't pay anything for package updates. I get what you're saying though, those servers cost money to run and maintain.

This is why they don't want you modifying it, because then it might not be compatible with the updaters, and they don't want to deal with that. If you modify it, they need to qualify it.

@Barmar I guess it comes down to what the definition of "modify" is in this context. I'm not modifying any source code at all. I'm only changing some config files, installing a few kernel modules to support hardware, and adding my employer's application to the image. These systems don't have an internet connection out in the field, so any package updates are done by me when I build a new OS image, then that image is distributed to the systems in the field. I don't need help resolving package update issues, so Canonical wouldn't have to deal with any issues like that.

@Barmar I think your collection of comments is essentially an answer. Can you write it up as such?

@quarague I'm not really sure how to formalize it -- I don't know the answer to the OP's "what is the definition of 'modify'?". [opensource.se] may be a better place to ask this, the experts there deal with these details all the time.

Gotta love when people downvote your question without commenting as to why. I think it's a valid and well-formatted question, so I really don't understand. Anyway, @Barmar I intend to return here and leave a comment/answer once my employer figures out how we're going to proceed.

I just got out of a meeting with Canonical. They clarified their position on what exactly constitutes modifying an Ubuntu image, which is basically doing anything to it at all.
In a nutshell, Canonical takes the position that any change from a default installation is considered modifying it. That includes installing or removing any packages.

+1 for following up with a "from the horse's mouth" response, although it perhaps should be noted that they may not be totally impartial on the subject.
